# Can a momentum with no direction have size?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors

In a practice question, I stumbled across a graph of momentum vs. time. Regardless of units, the graph was a linear piece-wise graph. Positive momentum was associated on the graph was associated with the momentum (in that time period) moving to the right. Similarly, negative/decreasing momentum on the graph was associated with the momentum moving to the left.

One of the pieces of the graph (representing a set time interval) was parallel to the y axis, meaning it neither increased nor decreased. I deduced that the direction of the momentum was neither to the left nor right. My question is, does that mean that the size of the momentum in that instance is zero? Or could the size of the momentum be existent?

I would think that size could be existent, just based on the equation :

*delta momentum = net force x delta time* i.e. $\Delta p = F_{net} \Delta t$.

Comment: In classical mechanics, momentum is a vector. Since what you’re describing isn’t one it can’t mean the vector that we use.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please make use of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) link and use MathJax to typeset equations like this $\text d p=F_{net}\times\text d t$

Comment: *One of the pieces of the graph ... was parallel to the y axis, meaning it neither increased nor decreased* Did you mean to write “parallel to the $t$-axis?

Comment: If you could post that graph here, it would help much for a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Your graph was plotting the component of the momentum vector in a particular direction.  If a line on the graph was parallel to the t axis, the the component was constant.  If it was parallel to the y axis, there was a (nearly) instantaneous change in the momentum (perhaps as a result of a collision).